# jenkins slaves not running on kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jnlp

i am trying to run slaves on my kubernetes cluster. My jenkins is deployed on ec2.
I am able to connect it with 1 of my cluster but when I am trying to connect and try running slave on another cluster by adding new cloud the pods are not getting scheduled and I am getting the following error on jenkins system logs:

```
Error in provisioning; agent=KubernetesSlave name: jnlptesting-qzq19, template=PodTemplate{id='ae363eec-1d72-4419-9c36-fe4a9a6308e3', name='jnlptesting', namespace='jenkins-ds', label='pods', podRetention='Never'}
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:204)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:457)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:68)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1095)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$200(SSLSocketImpl.java:72)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:815)
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Socket closed
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:262)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1303)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$300(SSLSocketImpl.java:72)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:831)
    at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
Caused: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at okio.Okio$4.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:232)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:285)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:241)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:354)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:226)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:215)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:127)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.intercept(BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.java:133)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.OIDCTokenRefreshInterceptor.intercept(OIDCTokenRefreshInterceptor.java:41)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.ImpersonatorInterceptor.intercept(ImpersonatorInterceptor.java:68)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.lambda$createHttpClient$3(HttpClientUtils.java:151)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:257)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:93)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:472)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:435)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleCreate(OperationSupport.java:250)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleCreate(BaseOperation.java:881)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.create(BaseOperation.java:341)
Also:   java.lang.Throwable: launched here
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer._connect(SlaveComputer.java:283)
    at hudson.model.Computer.connect(Computer.java:435)
    at hudson.slaves.CloudRetentionStrategy.start(CloudRetentionStrategy.java:73)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.executors.OnceRetentionStrategy.start(OnceRetentionStrategy.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.executors.OnceRetentionStrategy.start(OnceRetentionStrategy.java:46)
    at hudson.model.AbstractCIBase.updateComputer(AbstractCIBase.java:161)
    at hudson.model.AbstractCIBase.access$000(AbstractCIBase.java:43)
    at hudson.model.AbstractCIBase$2.run(AbstractCIBase.java:223)
    at hudson.model.Queue._withLock(Queue.java:1383)
    at hudson.model.Queue.withLock(Queue.java:1260)
    at hudson.model.AbstractCIBase.updateComputerList(AbstractCIBase.java:206)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.updateComputerList(Jenkins.java:1634)
    at jenkins.model.Nodes$2.run(Nodes.java:151)
    at hudson.model.Queue._withLock(Queue.java:1383)
    at hudson.model.Queue.withLock(Queue.java:1260)
    at jenkins.model.Nodes.addNode(Nodes.java:147)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.addNode(Jenkins.java:2157)
    at hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.lambda$update$6(NodeProvisioner.java:256)
    at hudson.model.Queue._withLock(Queue.java:1383)
    at hudson.model.Queue.withLock(Queue.java:1260)
    at hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.update(NodeProvisioner.java:225)
    at hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.lambda$suggestReviewNow$1(NodeProvisioner.java:183)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [create]  for kind: [Pod]  with name: [null]  in namespace: [jenkins-ds]  failed.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:64)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:72)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.create(BaseOperation.java:349)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.create(BaseOperation.java:84)
    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher.launch(KubernetesLauncher.java:136)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.lambda$_connect$0(SlaveComputer.java:294)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Mar 01, 2021 1:40:06 PM INFO org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesSlave _terminate
Terminating Kubernetes instance for agent jnlptesting-qzq19
```

Comment: what is your kubernetes-plugin version ? is it stop work after upgrade ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify the read time in the kubernetes plugin

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer? To what value you have changed it? It might be useful for other community members.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm [@rohit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13890059/rohit) answer.

In my case the agents were spawning in an AWS EKS cluster which was very close to the node limit, thus quite slow in providing a new agent.

The issue appeared out of nowhere (so it seemed). But actually it appeared when the number of nodes increased.
After increasing the limit to 60s (to be sure) from the default 15s, it worked.

The logs looked similar as the ones in the first post.